# PHP: Formatting the day number suffix in php with date()

Tags: php, date, formatting

I feel a bit silly for this one, but is there a *more elegant way to format the day number suffix* (st, th) other than by having to call the date() 3 times?

What I am trying to output in html:

```
<p>January, 1<sup>st</sup>, 2011</p>
```

What I am doing now (feels very heavy) in php:

```
//I am omitting the <p> tags:
echo date('M j',$timestamp)  
. '<sup>' . date('S', $timestamp) . '</sup>'  
. date(' Y', $timestamp);
```

Anyone knows a better way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just have to escape characters that are interpreted by the date function.

```
echo date('M j<\sup>S</\sup> Y'); // < PHP 5.2.2
echo date('M j<\s\up>S</\s\up> Y'); // >= PHP 5.2.2
```

At [PHP date documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you have a list with all characters replaced by their special meaning.

Comment: This solution give me output like `Jul 12<sup>th</sup> 2023`. Any suggestion? Please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
echo date('M j\<\s\u\p\>S\<\/\s\u\p\> Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: +1. I had written 80% when I saw a someone answering the question.

Comment: you can add any text you like into the php Date() function as part of the string, just ensure you escape reserved characters with a \, as shown in Trevor's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `date` function allows you to put in any string that you want, provided that you escape all format characters.

```
echo date('M j<\s\up>S<\/\s\up> Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: You had the "S" for the English ordinal suffix escaped, which is wrong. I have corrected that for you.

Comment: when I used it, results me like `Jul 12<sup>th</sup> 2023`. Is this ok?